# How to map from wrapped source properties to unwrapped destination

Tags: automapper

I'm trying to map a source structure where some properties are wrapped inside a `NonNull<T>` generic type (from GraphQL.Conventions library).

In practice, I want to use AutoMapper to map a structure:

```cs
public class SourceA
{
    public NonNull<SourceB> Sub { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }
}

public class SourceB
{
    public NonNull<string> Address { get; set; }
}
```

To a destination like this:

```cs
public class DestA
{
    public DestB Sub { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }
}

public class DestB
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

This is my setup:

```cs
var source = new NonNull<SourceA>(new SourceA
{
    Username = "Test user",
    Sub = new NonNull<SourceB>(new SourceB
    {
        Address = "Test Address"
    })
});

var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<SourceA, DestA>();
    cfg.CreateMap<NonNull<SourceA>, DestA>()
        .ConvertUsing((src, dst, ctx) =>
        {
            ctx.Mapper.Map(src.Value, dst);
            return dst;
        });
    cfg.CreateMap<SourceB, DestB>();
    cfg.CreateMap<NonNull<SourceB>, SourceB>()
        .ConvertUsing((src, dst, ctx) =>
        {
            ctx.Mapper.Map(src.Value, dst);
            return dst;
        });
}).CreateMapper();


var dest = mapper.Map<DestA>(source);
```

The above setup is the closest I could get, but it still throws this exception:

> Error mapping types.
>
> Mapping types: SourceA -> DestA MappingTest.Program+SourceA ->
>   MappingTest.Program+DestA
>
> Type Map configuration: SourceA -> DestA MappingTest.Program+SourceA
>   -> MappingTest.Program+DestA
>
> Destination Member: Sub

Anyone knows an easy way to do this (keeping in mind that I should be able to autogenerate the mapping configuration using T4 templates, if that matters at all)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found something that works.

```cs
var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<SourceA, DestA>();
    cfg.CreateMap<NonNull<SourceA>, DestA>().ConvertUsing((src, dst, ctx) => ctx.Mapper.Map<DestA>(src.Value));
    cfg.CreateMap<SourceB, DestB>();
    cfg.CreateMap<NonNull<SourceB>, DestB>().ConvertUsing((src, dst, ctx) => ctx.Mapper.Map<DestB>(src.Value));
}).CreateMapper();
```

Comment: Yes, and that can be made generic (`CreateMap(typeof(NonNull<>), typeof(object))`), but the right ConvertUsing overload is missing. I'll add it back in, but until then you can workaround it with AfterMap. You would also have to pass the destination object when calling map.